# Iterate through object properties with Symbol keys

Tags: javascript, symbols

I need to iterate through an object that has Symbols for keys. The following code returns an empty array.

```
const FOO = Symbol('foo');
const BAR = Symbol('bar');

const obj = {
  [FOO]: 'foo',
  [BAR]: 'bar',
}

Object.values(obj)
```

How can I iterate the values in `obj` so that I get `['foo', 'bar']`?

Comment: check `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can iterate over all the keys of Object (String and Symbol keys) with

```
Reflect.ownKeys()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys

Answer (score 27):

`Object.values` only gets the values of all enumerable named (string-keys) properties.

You need to use [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols):

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj).map(s => obj[s]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const FOO = Symbol('foo');
const BAR = Symbol('bar');

const temp3 = [
{
  id: 123,
  name: "John",
  [FOO]: 'foo',
  [BAR]: 'bar',
},
{
  id: 456,
  name: "Peter",
  [FOO]: 'foo',
  [BAR]: 'bar',
}
]
```

```
const horror = temp3.map((item) => {
    return {
        ...item,
        ...Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(item).reduce((acc, i) => ({ ...acc, [i.toString()]: item[i] }), {})
    }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(horror, null, 2))
```

returns:

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "John",
    "Symbol(foo)": "foo",
    "Symbol(bar)": "bar"
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "name": "Peter",
    "Symbol(foo)": "foo",
    "Symbol(bar)": "bar"
  }
]
```