# How to get properties of String Iterator Object using Object.keys?

Tags: javascript

Consider the object:- `"ok"[Symbol.iterator]().__proto__`

This resolves to an object:-

```
String Iterator {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "String Iterator", next: ƒ}
```

However `Object.keys()` does not list the object properties.

```
Object.keys("ok"[Symbol.iterator]().__proto__);
```

returns `[]length: 0__proto__: Array(0)`

Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate through object properties with Symbol keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372305/iterate-through-object-properties-with-symbol-keys)

Answer (score 3):

That's because [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) only lists [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) (so, basically: properties you've added yourself). As the MDN docs state, you can use [Object.getOwnPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) if you want to get the non-enumerable properties.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.keys()` retuns all string keys whereas in your case keys are `Symbols`
To get all `Symbol` keys use `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()`

```
Object.getOwnPropertySymbols("ok"[Symbol.iterator]().__proto__)
```

Output

```
[Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)]
```

You can also get the property names by using

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames("ok"[Symbol.iterator]().__proto__)
```

Output

```
["next"]
```